# Do all graphs have interval representations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The interval representation of a graph is the idea of depicting graph as layers of sequences of intervals. Two intervals intersect iff there exist an edge in the initial graph between corresponding vertices. Example can be seen here.[image: Example]

Do all graphs have interval representation?

Comment: Take K(n) n>4. Stack n interval one over another. All of them intersect and all of them are connected.

Comment: @ArnaudD. The nonplanar graph $K_5$ is an [interval graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph); however, the planar graph $C_4$ is not.

Comment: Oh, my bad then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the graph $C_4$ is not an [interval graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph).

Comment: thanks. Is there a characteristic from which you can recognize if a graph is interval graph or not?

Comment: I never studied them. If there is, the Wikipedia page I linked to in my answer will probably have something to say about it.

Comment: @guser, you can see many appropriate links to articles for many graph classes, including interval graphs [here](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_234.html). Particularly this class is recognizable in linear time. Articles give not a characteristic, but algorithms.